# Which flags are enabled by -O?

Tags: gcc, compiler-flags

My application has some portability issues when compiled with the -O flag.
I would like to find out which flag exactly triggers the problem, yet I am still unsuccessful..
I used all flags found in

```
gcc -c -Q -O --help=optimizers
```

but I still cannot reproduce the problem. Is it possible that the -O enables also additional flags?

Btw, the error I am getting is the following:

```
[Hein@Heinrich]$ ./parscons
./parscons: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by ./parscons)
./parscons: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./parscons)
```

Answer (score 2):

The list of flags enabled by  `gcc` for `-O` can be found here - [Optimize-Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

**From the doc:**

> -O
>   -O1 Optimize. Optimizing compilation takes somewhat more time, and a lot more memory for a large function. With -O, the compiler tries to
>   reduce code size and execution time, without performing any
>   optimizations that take a great deal of compilation time.
>
> -O turns on the following optimization flags:
>
> ```
>       -fauto-inc-dec 
>       -fbranch-count-reg 
>       -fcombine-stack-adjustments 
>       -fcompare-elim 
>       -fcprop-registers 
>       -fdce 
>       -fdefer-pop 
>       -fdelayed-branch 
>       -fdse 
>       -fforward-propagate 
>       -fguess-branch-probability 
>       -fif-conversion2 
>       -fif-conversion 
>       -finline-functions-called-once 
>       -fipa-pure-const 
>       -fipa-profile 
>       -fipa-reference 
>       -fmerge-constants 
>       -fmove-loop-invariants 
>       -fshrink-wrap 
>       -fsplit-wide-types 
>       -ftree-bit-ccp 
>       -ftree-ccp 
>       -fssa-phiopt 
>       -ftree-ch 
>       -ftree-copy-prop 
>       -ftree-copyrename 
>       -ftree-dce 
>       -ftree-dominator-opts 
>       -ftree-dse 
>       -ftree-forwprop 
>       -ftree-fre 
>       -ftree-phiprop 
>       -ftree-sink 
>       -ftree-slsr 
>       -ftree-sra 
>       -ftree-pta 
>       -ftree-ter 
>       -funit-at-a-time
> ```
>
> -O also turns on -fomit-frame-pointer on machines where doing so does not interfere with debugging.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I had already found your list and tried compiling my application with all those flags, but it still does not reproduce my portability issue.

Comment: What sort of issue is it that you are seeing?

Comment: I am compiling my application on one computer and running it on a second (which does not have the same libstdc++.so6 version)